# Can't access shared preference from my java class. android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I have 2 **activities** (login and webcall). Login stores user details (using Shared Preferences). I've generated all the classes from the webservice wsdl.
In my webcall **activity**, I call a WebServiceSoapCall class i.e. 
`WebServiceSoapCall webcall = new WebServiceSoapCall;`
**this class** passes parameters to another class like this:
        `HttpTransportBasicAuth(url,password,username);`
Since these are regular **classes**  and not activities (HttpTransportBasicAuth and WebServiceSoapCall ), I am not able to retrieve these parameters from my Shared preference within them:
        `SharedPreference mypref = getsharedpreference(SP_NAME,Contect.MODE_PRIVATE);`
getsharedpreference() doesn't work in classes only in activities. Right now I'm explicitly passing these parameters: 
        `HttpTransportBasicAuth("myurl","myusername","mypassword");`
I want to avoid using this hardcoding for obvious reasons.

Comment: Youll have to try and clarify that or just add the java classes because as for now you question is not clear.

Comment: See this, from the ... Elena http://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/5885018

Comment: I have tried using shared preferences just like in all the examples on this site and the tutorails online.. It works fine when you use them inside activities but not when you are trying to retrieve the information from a java class

Comment: You have to pass a `Context` object into the Java class in order to get the SharedPrefereneces

Comment: hi Elena, when you use the getSharedPreference() from within a class, it doesn't work because it is not an activity..hence my problem :(

Comment: Elena is the person who posted the answer in the other post. She isn't commenting here, so you can't say hi

Comment: thanks cricket_007 i managed to pass a context in the class and everything worked fine. I also had to make another class that stores and retrieves data to the sharedpreference.
thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an extra parameter, a `Context`, and call `context.getSharedPreferences()`